# Compare a nvarchar(max) value with a column

Tags: sql-server, search

I'm trying to search if a nvarchar(max) row match with any keyword of a column in other table.

Something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) case when c.Keyword IS NOT NULL THEN 'Match'
               ELSE 'No Match' END
FROM sourceTable SC
LEFT JOIN KeywordTable C on sc.LargeText like '%'+c.Keyword+'%'
WHERE SC.Id = @Id
```

This has performances issues, the KeywordTable isn't large (1.000 rows)

All the examples are the inverse scenario, search in large text rows and one keyword, this is one large text and many keywords in a table.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: it has performance issues because that `LIKE` clause makes it nonSARGable meaning it can't use an index. Update your post with the actual execution plan. Ideally via https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ Also, why the top(1)? You have no order by so you must not care which row comes back... and since you are only returning the case statement and no other columns you are wanting a random 'Match' or 'Not match' which makes this query kind of pointless unless SC.Id is unique in which the top 1isn't needed

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, but I need to accomplish that type of search, there is any way to create a index or modify the query to do that?

Comment: Thanks Sean I will read that.

Comment: Scsimon. The idea is to find if the text match with one criteria, no matter witch one, the top 1 is to improve performance since doesn't matter wich criteria is matched. The point of this is to identify suspicious content in a text for an aplication

Comment: Yes, it involves [full text index](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and then the use of [CONTAINS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or maybe `FREETEXT`. You can read about those [here, as a comparision](https://www.sitepoint.com/sql-server-full-text-search-protips-part-2-contains-vs-freetext/) i encourage you to research the pros and cons, and maintenance involved in doing this. if `Criteria` is a comma separated string, normalize your data to avoid this